# How to compute object property in database with C# code?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

As an example let's say my database has a table with thousands of ships with every ship potentially having thousands of passengers as a navigation property:

```
public DbSet<Ship> Ship { get; set; }
public DbSet<Passenger> Passenger { get; set; }

public class Ship
{
    public List<Passenger> passengers { get; set; }
    //properties omitted for example
}

public class Passenger
{
    //properties omitted for example
}
```

The example use case is that someone is fetching **all** ships per API and would like to know for each ship whether it is empty (0 passengers), so the returned JSON will contain a list of ships each with a bool whether it is empty.

My current code seems very inefficient (including all passengers just to determine if a ship is empty):

```
List<Ship> ships = dbContext.Ship
    .Include(x => x.passengers)
    .ToList();
```

and later when the ships are serialized to JSON:

```
jsonShip.isEmpty = !ship.passengers.Any();
```

I would like a more performant (and not bloated) alternative to including all passengers. What options do I have?

I have looked at [computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns) but they only seem to support sql as string. If possible I would like to stay in the C# code world, so for example having a property which is set correctly by being automatically woven in the SQL query would be optimal.

Comment: How have you determined that your code is inefficient?  Did you measure its execution time and found that it fails a specific software requirement?

Comment: You haven't actually shown *how* you're computing the number of passengers associated with a ship. All you're doing right now is retrieving all the ships with their associated passengers into memory. EF supports filtering the data it returns - it can even filter on the database side prior to retrieving all the results. Did you look into how to filter data with EF? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/) is a great place to get started when using any framework.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Your comment probably aims at premature optimization. My question is not aiming for a concrete use case in one place but for the knowledge what my options are to compute values on the database side with C# code. Might come handy some day.

Comment: @mason in the most simple way: `bool shipIsEmpty = !ship.passengers.Any();` . Can you point me in the right direction? I don't see how a filter would be able to determine if a ship has passengers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Data Transfer Object for `Ship` that reflects the shape of your JSON result, like -

```cs
public class ShipDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmpty { get; set; }
}
```

Then use projection in your query -

```cs
var ships = dbCtx.Ships
            .Select(p => new ShipDto
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                Name = p.Name,
                IsEmpty = !p.Passengers.Any()
            })
            .ToList();
```

Usually, APIs need to produce responses of various shapes and DTOs give you well defined models to represent the shape of your API response. Domain entities are not always suitable for this.

If your domain entity (`Ship`) has a lot of properties, then copying all those properties in the `.Select()` method might be cumbersome. You can use `AutoMapper` to map them for you. `AutoMapper` has a `ProjectTo<T>()` method that can generate the SQL and return the projected result. For example, you can achieve the above result with a mapping configuration -

```cs
CreateMap<Ship, ShipDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.IsEmpty, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => !s.Passengers.Any()));
```

and a query -

```cs
var ships = Mapper.ProjectTo<ShipDto>(dbCtx.Ships).ToList();
```

assuming all other properties in `ShipDto` are named similar as in `Ship` entity.

**EDIT :**
If you don't want a DTO model -

1. you can add a `NotMapped` property in `Ship` model -

```cs
public class Ship
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsEmpty { get; set; }
    
    public List<Passenger> passengers { get; set; }
}
```

and then do the query like -

```cs
var ships = dbCtx.Ships
            .Select(p => new Ship
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                Name = p.Name,
                IsEmpty = !p.Passengers.Any()
            })
            .ToList();
```

2. You can return an anonymous type -

```cs
var ships = dbCtx.Ships
            .Select(p => new
            {
                Id = p.Id,
                Name = p.Name,
                IsEmpty = !p.Passengers.Any()
            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: That would indeed be a good solution but that's knowledge I already have. The use case is to return **all** ships with a property whether they are empty. I tried to make that more clear in the question.

Comment: `p.Passengers.Count == 0` can be made more efficient by replacing it with `!p.Passengers.Any()`.

Comment: @Tom My apologies, if I failed to interpret your question. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I just found that out. Thanks. I'll use it in the updated answer.

Comment: @atiyar A projection with a Select method is exactly what's needed! Executed on the database and written in C# code. The DTO is a nice bonus but it also works with an anonymous type. The only (theoretically) better way would be to be able to directly define a projection for a [NotMapped] isEmpty property on the original ship object but that is not a feature of ef core currently.

Comment: @Tom Its not theoretical, you can do that. Add a `[NotMapped]` method in `Ship` model and in the `.Select()` method, replace `new ShipDto` with `new Ship`. And yes you can use anonymous type too. I showed the approach with DTOs, because APIs require to produce various shapes of responses and DTOs gives you a well defined model to represent the shape of your API response. Domain entities are not always suitable to represent them.

Comment: @atiyar Nice, that's even better. I might start getting picky but a solution without the Select method would even be better. Like defining the logic of the isEmpty property in the OnModelCreating of the DbContext: `modelBuilder.Entity<Ship>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasPropertyMappingExecutedInDb(x => x.isEmpty = !x.passengers.Any());
});` Don't tell me theres also a solution for that : ).

Comment: @Tom You are being greedy  :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention correctly...

One way is to store the number of passengers inside each `Ship` entity. This can work well if you use Domain Driven Design, treat the `Ship` as an aggregate root, and only add or remove passengers through methods exposed on the given `Ship` entity, e.g. `RegisterPassenger()` / `RemovePassenger()`. Inside these methods, increment or decrement the passenger number along with adding or removing the passenger.

Then, obviously, you can query the `Ships` dbset with a `PassengerCount < 0` projection to the bool you need. And, again obviously, it won't even touch the `Passengers` table.

In traditional anemic domain ASP.NET systems this sort of data redundancy might be a bit more risky, because properties are usually publicly mutable, and you have multiple services that 'massage' the entities, which is a potential source of data integrity loss.